# Is there a `git log` summary that includes merge (only) and non-merge commits?

Tags: git, github

I don't mean simply `git log`, I know that lists everything.  I'm looking for a summary.

I'm not sure if this is the best practice or not, but I use both merge and squash style commits with git.  If a change is small and straight-forward, I don't see why it needs a merge commit, the commit is already atomic.  On the other hand, sometimes adding a logical function to code consists of multiple atomic steps, and I tend to use merge in this case, to avoid squashing multiple steps together.

What I'm wondering is if there is a good way to summarize this in the log.  That is, can I list only the merge commit (if and only if it is a merge commit) and otherwise list the non-merge commit?  This is tied to editing the merge commit so it describes what feature is being added, of course.

It seems like the `git log --merges` is close, but it doesn't list the squashed commits, so is an incomplete history.

[edit based on comment about rebasing] I was thinking my question applied to both git and github, but the question from one of the comments made me realize it doesn't exactly.  Github allows you to merge a pull request or squash it (it also allows rebasing a commit, but that is off-topic I think).  Merging a Pull Request results in a merge commit with the set of commits in the pull request, while a `Squash commit` is basically the same as cherry-picking the commit into the target branch (or squashing if there are more than one commit in the PR).

Comment: i thought when you rebase you rewrite history and so you "loose" history...

Comment: A squash-merge is just an ordinary commit, in the end. There's no way to distinguish it from any other ordinary commit, unless you make such a distinction yourself (e.g., strictly guarantee some `git log --grep`able message in squash commits that never occurs in any other ordinary commits).

Comment: That said, if the only commits you ever make *directly* on `master` (or whatever starting point you choose) are either merges or squashes, then following each commit backwards from the tip, you have either a merge (in which case you want to summarize it as a merge) or a non-merge (in which case you want to summarize it as a squash-merge). The way do to *that* in `git log` is to use `--first-parent`, which follows only the *first* parent of each commit. An ordinary commit has only a first parent, while a merge has a second parent that is the chain that got merged.

Comment: @torek Nice!  Please turn your comment into an answer.  `--first-parent` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given the way you are using Git (which I think is a very good way, but opinions are frowned-upon here on StackOverflow :-) ) you can get just what you want using the `--first-parent` option.

#### Long description

As a quick summary reminder, when you use `git merge --squash` (or the "merge via squash" clicky button on [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github)), what Git does in the end is to make an ordinary commit that has, as its content, the same *content* you would get for a true merge; but this new ordinary commit is just that—an ordinary commit—with only a single parent, unrelated to the commits that were to be merged.

If you were to make a real merge you would get this:

```
* a000000 (master) merge feature/tall
|\
| * ccccccc (feature/tall) fixing something trivial
| * bbbbbbb oops, forgot the cat
| * aaaaaaa take a stab at implementing "tall"
|/
* 9999999 some commit or another
* 8888888 the history goes on ...
```

and so on.  But the whole A+B+C sequence for the feature doesn't need all the "oops" and "trivial fix" things to be saved away permanently, so we could instead just make the final commit:

```
* a000001 (master) implement the "tall" feature
|
| * ccccccc (feature/tall) fixing something trivial
| * bbbbbbb oops, forgot the cat
| * aaaaaaa take a stab at implementing "tall"
|/
* 9999999 some commit or another
* 8888888 the history goes on ...
```

and then toss out `feature/tall` entirely.  We then get this nice sequence in which the whole feature appears at once.

But, as you say in your question, sometimes it makes much more sense to introduce a feature in steps:

```
* f000000 (master) merge feature/short
|\
| * eeeeeee (feature/short) use the new facility to implement feature
| * ddddddd replace specific hack with new generic facility
| * bcdefed clean up an earlier specific hack
|/
* a000001 implement the "tall" feature
* 9999999 some commit or another
* 8888888 the history goes on ...
```

We can do this with a `--no-ff` merge (or the corresponding clicky button on GitHub—the same button, really, but set into a different mode).

As before, we can delete the label `feature/short` entirely since it's now done (well, done as far as we know, maybe it will need bug fixes in the future but that will be then, not now).

When viewing this history, suppose we could just tell Git: *Only look at the commits going straight down the left side of the history, please.*  Then we'd see the single commit that brought in `feature/tall` (even if the name is gone), as it's `a000001`; but before that, we'd also see, *as a single commit, as if it had been made by squashing* (only it wasn't and the full details are still there in the repository if we want them) the merge commit that brought in `feature/short`.

There is in fact a way to tell `git log` (and its script-oriented sister command `git rev-list`) to do just that.  The `--first-parent` flag tells Git that when it encounters a merge commit, it should, for display and graph-walking purposes, strip away the second parent of any merge.<sup>1</sup>  This leaves the rest of Git treating this commit, at least for the moment, as if it were an ordinary non-merge.  That's what a squash merge is too: a commit that was made by the merging action, the merge-as-a-verb part of Git, but was added to the commit graph as an ordinary, single-parent commit.

Hence, `git log --first-parent` (optionally with `-mp` as well: note that for patch purposes you will generally want `-m` to avoid combined diff behavior) will get what you want here.

---

<sup>1</sup>A merge commit with more than two parents—called an *octopus merge*—is stripped of *all but the first*, hence the option name, "first parent".  Most merges just have two parents, though; GitHub itself cannot make octopus merges.

Comment: `--first-parent` is all I need! Thanks!